# Generic classes - when to use and why

Tags: c#, generics

i understand what they are, I'm just wondering when is the best time to use them.

My first thought was - when we are building a (static) utility class which should perform certain operations on different data types. 
Ergo, it is a good practice to use generic methods to avoid numerous overloads of a certain method? Please comment on this.

I have a small example class. It's just for the sake of an example.

```
public static class Math<T> where T : operator +, operator -
{
    public static T Add(T a1, T a2)
    {
        return a1+a2;
    }

    public static T Subtract(T a1, T a2)
    {
        return a1 - a2;
    }
}
```

1. Would this be a good usage of generic classes and methods, e.g I wish to add and subtract ints, doubles.. etc.. with the minimum amount of code ?
2. Why won't this compile? I've tried this as well as modifying the class signature:

   `public static class Math<T> where T : struct`

I understand that I must specify whether the Type parameter is of reference or of value type. 
I did that by specifying that T must be constrained as a value type, so why am I still getting error that the operator + and/or - cannot be applied to T (which should specifically be a value type)

Comment: I don't think you can use `operator +` as generic constraint in c#. Check this blog post: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: Unfortunately that particular example is not valid C# and won't work. Generics don't support this. One way to achieve this, although I doubt I'd ever use it, is to simply pass two arguments as `dynamic` and duck-type the operators, it'll "just work".

Comment: You can apply operators to only those types than have their use defined. Just because T is a value type doesn't mean the compiler knows how T + T works. If you define a struct with 10 fields, each of different type, how do you want to add it? By adding values of all fields? Adding only two? And so on.

Answer (score 4):

1. No this wouldn't be a good use. Generics are to provide type-safe data structures without knowing the type. Generic constraints allow you to specify some semantics about the type, such as implementing an interface, having a default constructor, or being a class or struct.

   Please see these MSDN articles:

   - [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
   - [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

   .
2. It won't compile because the `operator +` parts are not valid constraints.

   Being a value type does not infer operators such as `+` or `-`, it only infers value-type semantics (inherits `object`, is a value type, cannot be null, has a default constructor).

---

**Generic Constraints**

Generic constraints help the compiler give you more from your `T`. An unconstrained generic can only be proven to be `object`, so you only get access to `object` members on the argument.

If you state: `public void Foo<T>() where T : new()`

The compiler can prove that your type has a default public parameterless constructor. This is the purpose of constraints, it forces the types that can be party to the generic to conform to a contract.

There are various constraints, but as you have found there are some limitations. Interestingly, there are limitations in C# that do not exist in IL, as explored by Jon Skeet in his [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library that exposes `enum` constraints to C#.

Answer (score 2):

As written by others the `operator+` isn't a valid constraint. If what you want is to make some generic math, you can use something like:

```
public static class Add<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Do;

    static Add()
    {
        var par1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var par2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var add = Expression.Add(par1, par2);

        Do = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(add, par1, par2).Compile();
    }
}

public static class Math<T>
{
    public static T Add(T a1, T a2)
    {
        return Add<T>.Do(a1, a2);
    }
```

This will create and compile an `Expression` that does the operation and then cache it in a generic static class.

Sadly with this method you lose the static checking of you compiler (you could do something like:

```
object res = Math<object>.Add(new object(), new object());
```

and it would compile correctly. At runtime it would explode.)

In general you can't make a constraint asking for a specific method (static or non-static) or a specific property to be present (operators are like static methods) (with a single exception: the `new()` constraint that asks for a public parameterless constructor). What you can ask is for an interface to be implemented, or for a base class to be present, or for the generic parameter to be a `class` or a `struct` (where the two must be meant as "reference type" and "value type", and not simply as `class` and `struct`). Sadly there are no interfaces `IAddable`, `ISubtractable`, ... and even if you built them, `int`, `double`... wouldn't implement them, and to make it worse, in .NET you can't have generic specializations (a trick of C++ where you define a generic `Math<T>` and then you define special "cases" explicitly, like `Math<int>`, `Math<double>` and so on)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious use case for generic classes is data structures which can then store any type of data without having to treat it all as instances of `object`. You probably use these all the time - `IList<T>`, `IDictionary<K, V>` etc. It lets you store things where you don't know the type when you're writing the structure while retaining type safety. The trick being that you also don't know anything about the type you're storing so you can't do much with it.

Thus generic constraints, which let you say something is a reference type or a value type, or has a parameterless constructor, or implements an interface. These come in useful when you're writing a generic class which has to do something with instances of the parameterised type. Might seem useless - why not just use an interface type as the parameter type and avoid generics altogether? Because generic constraints can force a parameter to conform to more than one interface - something you can't specify in a normal parameter type. Thus you can write a function:

```
public static void Frobnicate<T>(T thing)
    where T : IList<int>, IDisposable
{
    // ...
}
```

You can also stick a single base class name in there too. This is far, far more flexible than specifying concrete types. Sure you could create an interface which inherits from `IList<int>` and `IDisposable` but you can't retrofit all disposable lists of integers that might be out there to implement it.

You could also do it at runtime using reflection to inspect things, but this kind of thing is far better handled by the compiler, IMO.